# Android - Firebase - TaskSnapshot - Method should only be accessed within private scope? with android studio 2.3

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

    Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
    }
});
```

**Error TaskSnapshot** - Method should only be accessed within private scope while using android studio 2.3.

Comment: Hi there, I just read this question and a one time google search has given me [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41105586/4112725). Anyway, welcome to StackOverflow :D

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be a bug, maybe it will be fixed in the next version. In the mean time, try this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
```