# Android - Firebase - TaskSnapshot - Method should only be accessed within private scope

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code snippet in my onSuccessListener() to save the download URL of the file I uploaded.

```
 DatabaseReference downloadURLRef = rootRef.child("Child").child(value);
 Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
 downloadURLRef.setValue(downloadUrl);
```

I get this error:

```
Error TaskSnapshot - Method should only be accessed within private scope while using android studio 2.3.
```

When I followed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42921414/android-firebase-tasksnapshot-method-should-only-be-accessed-within-privat) and suppressed the warning, my app crashes on upload, and the upload fails. [Here's the error for that.](https://pastebin.com/raw/bxq8mm6u)

What gives? This is straight from the Firebase documentation too.

EDIT: Upload code.

```
    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    storageRef = storage.getReference(date + "/" + filename);
    uploadTask = storageRef.putFile(Uri.fromFile(file));

    // Register observers to listen for when the download is done or if it fails
    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            // TODO: Fix this bullshit
            DatabaseReference downloadURLRef = rootRef.child("Child").child(value);
            Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
            downloadURLRef.setValue(downloadUrl);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Post the code that performs the upload.

Comment: @BobSnyder there you go

Comment: If you comment out the three lines to get `downloadUrl` and store it, does the crash not occur?

Comment: @BobSnyder that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save `downloadUrl` as a string, not a `Uri` object:

```
    DatabaseReference downloadURLRef = rootRef.child("Child").child(value);
    Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
    downloadURLRef.setValue(downloadUrl.toString()); // <= CHANGE
```

Comment: I also removed the @NonNull from the parameters in `onFailure`, for anyone who stumbles upon this response and it doesn't work.