# Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

[image: Screen Image]

This method should only be accessed from tests or within private scope less... (Ctrl+F1)
This inspection looks at Android API calls that have been annotated with various support annotations (such as RequiresPermission or UiThread) and flags any calls that are not using the API correctly as specified by the annotations.  Examples of errors flagged by this inspection:
Passing the wrong type of resource integer (such as R.string) to an API that expects a different type (such as R.dimen).
Forgetting to invoke the overridden method (via super) in methods that require it
Calling a method that requires a permission without having declared that permission in the manifest
Passing a resource color reference to a method which expects an RGB integer value.

https://discussions.udacity.com/t/uri-downloadurl-tasksnapshot-getdownloadurl/232533?u=tahirs95

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/41105586/4815718.  The warning is a bug in Android Studio--fixed in the next release.

Comment: Android Studio bug report here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=235661

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Firebase - TaskSnapshot - Method should only be accessed within private scope?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41105586/android-firebase-tasksnapshot-method-should-only-be-accessed-within-privat)

Answer (score 1):

I know its too late but still my answer might help someone who have this problem after june 1 2018...
because firebase has changed its policy and some features  a little bit after june 1 2018. previous method of getting download uri will give you something you don't want .

try this

```
 StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

                final StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("folder_name_of_firebse_storage/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());


                UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(your_image_uri_which_need_to_be_uploaded);

                Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            throw task.getException();
                        }

                        // Continue with the task to get the download URL
                        return ref.getDownloadUrl();
                    }
                }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();




                            //this is the uri you needed... 


                      uploaded_image_url = downloadUri.toString();



                        } else {
                            // Handle failures
                            // ...
                            Toast.makeText(EditUserProfile.this, "Image uploading failed ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    }
                });
```

Hope this helped!!!

Answer (score 0):

*try this code*

@SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests") Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

Comment: Add some description why your answer is useful or answer of OP.

Answer (score 0):

this should work!!

```
Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getResult().getDownloadUrl();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
```

Change the variable name:

```
Task<Uri> downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
```

It will work.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are on version 10.0.1 
do this instead so it will work

```
@SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTesting") Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
```

Answer (score -1):

The method `getDownloadUrl()` returns a task.
Just change line

```
Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
```

to

```
Task<Uri> downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
```