# How to get file URL after uploading them to Firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Once you have uploaded a file to Firebase how can you get it's URL so that you can store that for later use? I want to write the URL to a Firebase Database so that other users can access the image.

I am uploading the file like so:

```
public void uploadFile()
{

    StorageReference filepath = mstorageRef.child("folder").child(filename);

    Uri File= Uri.fromFile(new File(mFileName));

    filepath.putFile(File).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MtActivity.this, "Upload Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

I have confirmed that the files are in fact uploading so now I just need the URL which I can write to my Database. However when I tried to do this:

```
Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getDownloadUrl();
```

It gives me an error and says `This method should only be accessed from tests or within private scope`

I'm not sure what that means and I also don't know why I would be getting that error since I'm following [this example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files) provided by Firebase.

Is there a new way of getting the URL?

Also, is that URL unique to that item in particular? Meaning if I store it to a database and try to access it later will I be able to do so?

Comment: You should write `taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl()`, instead of `taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getDownloadUrl()`

Comment: @AnggrayudiH I tried that and it gives me the same error message. For some reason it just won't let me call the method inside of my `addOnSuccessListener()` method.

Comment: With regard to the error you're seeing, have you seen [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41105586/4625829)?

Comment: Check this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50158921/firebase-storage-retrieves-a-long-lived-download-url-using-getdownloadurl-no it works for me.

Answer (score 42):

You're using `UploadTask.getDownloadUrl()` which is deprecated. You can use [StorageReference.getDownloadUrl()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url).

In your case you can try [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files#download_data_via_url) as -

```
 filepath.putFile(File).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot)
    {
         filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        Uri downloadUrl = uri;
                       //Do what you want with the url
                    }
        Toast.makeText(MtActivity.this, "Upload Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Take care that `StorageReference.getDownloadUrl()` returns Task, which must be handled asynchronously, you cannot do `Uri downloadUrl = photoRef.getDownloadUrl().getResult();` else you will get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Task is not yet complete`

Comment: String usableUrl = downloadUrl.toString(); after Uri downloadUrl = uri;

Comment: why is there a need to attach an `addOnSuccessListener` with `getDownloadUrl()`? since the path where the file is uploaded is a very small string, i assume there must be a way to retrieve the path from the `taskSnapshot` recieved in`..putFile(...).addonSuccesslistener(.<i.e here>.)` ?

Comment: @anshsachdeva You can visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url for further digging. I think you'll find this link helpful too - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/UploadTask.TaskSnapshot.html

 If you find another way out add/update the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This method works too and is a little bit simpler.

It's not something "incredible", but it reduces your code to a few lines. Hope that it's a helpful answer.

```
StorageReference filepath = mstorageRef.child("folder").child(filename);
filepath.putFile(File).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot){
            Uri downloadUrl = filepath.getDownloadUrl();  // here is Url for photo  
            Toast.makeText(MtActivity.this, "Upload Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned above, `StorageReference.getDownloadUrl()`
returns Task.

Here is my code:

```
        filepath.putFile(imageUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){

                    filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                            Uri downloadUri = uri;
                            String download_url = uri.toString();
                            mUserDatabase.child("image").setValue(download_url).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                              @Override

                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                   if(task.isSuccessful()) {

                                          mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                                          Toast.makeText(SettingActivity.this, "Successfully uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                   }else {
                                       Toast.makeText(SettingActivity.this, "Error happened during the upload process", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                   }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });


                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(SettingActivity.this, "Error happened during the upload process", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is hot I did it**

1) This is my Upload and get http url code:

```
UploadTask uploadTask = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("id").child("filename")
                                .putFile(uri);
                        Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                            @Override
                            public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    throw task.getException();
                                }

                                // Continue with the task to get the download URL
                                return FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(user.getUid()).child(avatarName).getDownloadUrl();
                            }
                        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(user.getUid())
                                            .child(avatarName)
                                            .child("avatar_image")
                                            .setValue(downloadUri.toString());
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    // Handle failures
                                    // ...
                                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

2) This my onActivityResult code after pickup image from gallery

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        uri = data.getData();

        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
            // Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));
            ivAvatarPic.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            //ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            //imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
val imageGalleryRef = storageReference?.child(name + "_gallery")
            val uploadTask = imageGalleryRef.putFile(file)
            uploadTask.addOnFailureListener({ e ->
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure sendFileFirebase " + e.message)
            }).addOnCompleteListener(
                    object : OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> {
                        override fun onComplete(p0: Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>) {
                            imageGalleryRef.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener { e ->
                                run {
                                     downloadUrl = e.toString() // e is image download Uri
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
 filepath.putFile(File).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
         @Override
         public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                 String fileUri = task.getResult().getUploadSessionUri().toString();
                         // Do whatever you want with fileUri 

                        }
                   }
            }) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                String category = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                                String title = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.post_title)).getText().toString();
                                String description = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.post_description)).getText().toString();
                                final Post post = new Post(userId, category, title, description, latitude, longitude, true);
                                post.setAddressList(addressLine);
                                post.setContact(contact);

                                if (addressLine != null) {
                                    post.setPlace(addressLine.split(",")[2]);
                                }
                                post.setId(key);
                                post.setImage(uri.toString());
                                databaseReference.setValue(post).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.post_title)).setText("");
                                            ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.post_description)).setText("");
                                            postImageButton.setImageURI(null);
                                            progressBarDialog.dismiss();
                                            Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Your request is sucessfully completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        } else if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            progressBarDialog.dismiss();
                                            Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Your request is not completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }

                                    }
                                });
                            }

                        });
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

change the **URI** to **URL**

```
val urlTask = uploadTask.continueWith { task ->
            if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                task.exception?.let {
                    throw it
                }
            }


            spcaeRef.downloadUrl
        }.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {

                val downloadUri = task.result

                //URL
                val url = downloadUri!!.result

            } else {
                //handle failure here
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ionic 5 + capacitor, this is how I ended up being able to both monitor upload and get the finished file name.

The code was collected from google's own documentation + some google search (https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/ionic-firebase-image-upload among others).

It is using canvas (as far as I understand) to generate a base64 string from an image. That worked, where ionic's File and Base64 didn't.

On the page, I have an <ion-progressbar> showing the percentage (this.downloadProgress) if it is > 0. I also have an <ion-img> with src=this.imageUrl that shows the picture when it's uploaded.

I couldn't get any of the techniques in above answers to work, wouldn't even compile. But I don't know enough to know why anyway.

Another caveat was that some of the example code used function() instead of arrow syntax

> encodeImageUri(imageURI, function(image64) {

which needs rewriting to arrow syntax to bind/pass in "this" to the function called, like here:

> encodeImageUri(imageURI, image64 => {

```
    uploadImage(imageURI) {
    console.log(`try upload ${imageURI}`)
      let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
      let imageRef = storageRef.child('image').child('imageName');
      this.encodeImageUri(imageURI, image64 => {

        // create upload task
        const uplTask = imageRef.putString(image64, 'data_url');

        uplTask.on('state_changed',
          snapshot => {
            var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes);
            console.log('Upload is ' + progress * 100 + '% done'); // might display this somewhere
            this.downloadProgress = progress; // update progress bar
          },
          error => {
            console.log('upload error');
          },
          () => {
            uplTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()
              .then(downloadURL => {
                console.log('File available at', downloadURL);
                this.imageUrl = downloadURL;
                this.downloadProgress = -1; // negative values hide the progress bar
              });        
          }
        );
      });
  }

  encodeImageUri(imageUri, callback) {
    var c = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function () {
      var aux:any = this;
      c.width = aux.width;
      c.height = aux.height;
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      var dataURL = c.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
      callback(dataURL);
    };
    img.src = imageUri;
  };
```

Of course this is kind of boring since it's always overwriting the same Firebase Storage file :) But that's fixable.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for as I am using Kotlin. This is what worked for me in my current project. I hope it will help someone else in the future.

Firstly I'm getting the image from the camera or from the gallery.
I'm using a current timestamp to make file names unique.

```
fun uploadFileFromMemory() {

        showLoading()

        val currentTimestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()

        val storage = Firebase.storage("Your storage url")

        // Create a storage reference from our app
        val storageRef = storage.reference

        // Create a reference to "mountains.jpg"
        val mountainsRef = storageRef.child("images/picture$currentTimestamp.jpg")

        // Get the data from an adminImageView as bytes
        adminImageView.isDrawingCacheEnabled = true
        adminImageView.buildDrawingCache()
        val bitmap = (adminImageView.drawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
        val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos)
        val data = baos.toByteArray()

        var uploadTask = mountainsRef.putBytes(data)

        val urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask { task ->
            if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                task.exception?.let {
                    throw it
                }
            }
            mountainsRef.downloadUrl
        }.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                val downloadUri = task.result

                updateServicePicture(downloadUri.toString())

            } else {
                hideLoading()

                showToast("Something went wrong")
            }
        }
```

After that, I am getting the URL of the newly updated file to update the picture URL property in my firestore database using this function.

```
fun updateServicePicture(url: String) {

        val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

        val id = arguments?.getString("id")

        if (id !== null) {

            val ref = db.collection("services").document(id)

// Set the "isCapital" field of the city 'DC'
            ref
                .update("picture", url)
                .addOnSuccessListener { Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully updated!")

                    hideLoading()

                    showToast("Picture has been successfully updated")
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.w(TAG, "Error updating document", e)

                    hideLoading()

                    showToast("Something went wrong")
                }

        }
    }
```

hideLoading(), showloading() and showToast() are my functions for progressbar and toast. 
I hope this helps someone out.
With the documentation and some testing, I eventually got it to work. Happy coding everyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Future<List<String>> uploadImages(List<String> filepaths) async {
    List<String> uploadUrls = [];

    await Future.wait(filepaths.map((String filepath) async {
      FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage(storageBucket: 'gs://your-bucket-name.appspot.com');
      StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storage.ref().child("images/${basename(filepath)}").putFile(File(filepath));
      StorageTaskSnapshot storageTaskSnapshot;

      StorageTaskSnapshot snapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
      if (snapshot.error == null) {
        storageTaskSnapshot = snapshot;
        final String downloadUrl = await storageTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
        uploadUrls.add(downloadUrl);

        print('Upload success');
      } else {
        print('Error from image repo ${snapshot.error.toString()}');
        throw ('This file is not an image');
      }
    }), eagerError: true, cleanUp: (_) {
      print('eager cleaned up');
    });

    return uploadUrls;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you try  `taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl()`?
if that also doesn't work you can get the image location in success listener by `mstorageRef.child("folder").child(filename).toString()`

Comment: I tried `taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl()` but it gives the same error. Also, how would I ever use the other method you showed me? Also, what would the other method do for me? How would I get the file back?

Comment: The Url is nothing but firebase path where image is stored so on upload success you should know that a path is being created on storage so use the same storage reference o which you saved and make it to String ..in your code `filepath.toString()`

Comment: That makes sense. But if I'm in another activity and want to access that image, how would I do that? Since I don't have access to `mstorageRef` how would I access the image?

Comment: In my work images are always associated with object data so get the image url store in mDatabase with object's data then retrieve the path of image in database from any activity

Comment: Exactly! If I had the URL then I could just access the image but how do I get that? If I use `mstorageRef.child("folder").child(filename).toString()` I will get the storage location and not the HTTP URL.

Comment: even with `taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl()` you'll only get storage reference location use Glide to display image from this location

Answer (score -2):

Try This :

```
final Uri uri = data.getData();

StorageReference filepath = mStorageRef.child("folder").child(filename);
filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new 

OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

            Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
            //Getting url where image is stored
            //downloadUri will store image URI
        }
    });
```