# Firebase Storage "retrieves a long lived download URL" using getDownloadUrl() now deprecated

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

This `getDownloadUrl()` method showed deprecated after updating to

> 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.2'

Nothing on the official site to another way to achieve the url, So there's any way to achieve the Url in non deprecated way?

```
/** @deprecated */
@Deprecated
@Nullable
public Uri getDownloadUrl() {
    StorageMetadata var1;
    return (var1 = this.getMetadata()) != null ? var1.getDownloadUrl() : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you be specific about the version of firebase-storage that you're using?  I don't see that in StorageReference in 15.0.0.

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the docs it says this:

> The `getDownloadUrl()` and `getDownloadUrls()` methods of the `StorageMetadata` class are now deprecated. Use `getDownloadUrl()` from `StorageReference` instead.

So you need to use `getDownloadUrl()` that is inside the `StorageReference`

> `public Task<Uri> getDownloadUrl ()`
>
> Asynchronously retrieves a long lived download URL with a revokable token. This can be used to share the file with others, but can be revoked by a developer in the Firebase Console if desired.

more information here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference#getDownloadUrl()

Comment: Can you share the link to the docs that says its deprecated.
Also an example to how to use **getDownloadUrl that inside the storage reference** would be great

Comment: yes here https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#latest_sdk_versions

Comment: Noted, Thank you!

Comment: You can retrieve your StorageReference from your task using 
`taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl()`

Answer (score 4):

```
  final StorageReference filePath = mImageStore.child("profile_images").child("full_image").child(userId + ".jpg");
                filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        //Bitmap hochladen
                        uploadBitMap(uri.toString());
                    }
                });strong text
```

Or

```
final UploadTask uploadTask = thumb_file.putBytes(thumb_bite);
        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                //Url laden
                taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        Map imageUrls = new HashMap();
                        imageUrls.put("image", fullImageUrl);
                        imageUrls.put("thumb_image", uri.toString());
                        //In database
                        mAlarmsDatabaseReference.updateChildren(imageUrls).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                //Progressbar beende + Bild wieder anzeigen
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                circleProfilePicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.ProfilbildUpdate), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }else{
                                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

final UploadTask uploadTask = thumb_file.putBytes(thumb_bite);
        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

```
            //Url laden
            taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                    Map imageUrls = new HashMap();
                    imageUrls.put("image", fullImageUrl);
                    imageUrls.put("thumb_image", uri.toString());
                    //In database
                    mAlarmsDatabaseReference.updateChildren(imageUrls).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            //Progressbar beende + Bild wieder anzeigen
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            circleProfilePicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.ProfilbildUpdate), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }else{
                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "FAILED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please edit your answer. Format the code block and add some description. Other wise you answer could be deleted by a moderator.