# URL generated by Firebase Storage does not allow access to the file

Tags: android, firebase, url, firebase-storage

I can't retrieve my images in Firebase Storage, when I try to access the Url of the image, shows this message: *"the X-Goog-Upload-Command header, which is not a valid X-Goog file"*. I can not access the files stored in Storage through the download URL. I ask for help, and the code bellow is how I'm uploading my files to the Storage and Database!

```
    if (pmcUri != null){

        // show the progress Dialog
        pmcProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pmcProgress.setTitle("Creating your Feed");
        pmcProgress.setMessage("...");
        pmcProgress.show();

        final StorageReference mChildStorage = pmcStorage.child("feedPhotos")
                .child(pmcUri.getLastPathSegment());
        mChildStorage.putFile(pmcUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                final Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getUploadSessionUri();

                FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();


                mChildStorage.getDownloadUrl();
                // save infos in Database with user ID as a Reference
                final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("feeds").child(uid.getUid());
                myRef.child("feed").setValue(setName);
                assert downloadUri != null;
                myRef.child("feedimg").setValue(downloadUri.toString());
                myRef.child("feedkey").setValue(uid.getUid());


                pmcProgress.dismiss();

                Intent intent = new Intent(create_feed.this, glime.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Why do you say "I can not access the files stored in Storage"? How are you checking the it?

Comment: Because I can upload a file (image) and see this file in Storage, but I can't have access via the URL. The URL does not work.

Comment: Where in code or in browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're reading your `downloadUri` variable is with:

```
final Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getUploadSessionUri();
```

Calling `getUploadSessionUri()` gives you a URI for th **upload** session, not the download URL for the file once it's finished uploading. The download URL is no longer available from the task snapshot, but instead requires an additional asynchronous call to the server.

When I have problems, I tend to fall back to the Firebase documentation, which has this handy [example of getting the download URL after an upload has completed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url):

> ```
> final StorageReference ref = storageRef.child("images/mountains.jpg");
> uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);
>
> Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
>     @Override
>     public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
>         if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
>             throw task.getException();
>         }
>
>         // Continue with the task to get the download URL
>         return ref.getDownloadUrl();
>     }
> }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
>     @Override
>     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
>         if (task.isSuccessful()) {
>             Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
>         } else {
>             // Handle failures
>             // ...
>         }
>     }
> });
> ```

So to get the download URL after the upload has completed, you start a new task that returns `ref.getDownloadUrl()`.

Also see:

- [How to use getdownloadurl in recent versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51056397/how-to-use-getdownloadurl-in-recent-versions), which shows the simplest possible snippet to get a download URL, and itself links to even more questions about this.
- [Firebase Storage getDownloadUrl() method can't be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50660975/firebase-storage-getdownloadurl-method-cant-be-resolved), which is the error you probably got leading you to use `getUploadSessionUri()`.
- [getDownloadURL isn't inputting the link i need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53127996/getdownloadurl-isnt-inputting-the-link-i-need)

Comment: It's working, thanks..I love you man, I'm learning code to improve my life and I was depressed that I couldn'tfix this problem, you save my year. THANK YOU SO MUCH. I wish you all the best and a  Merry Christmas.

Answer (score 1):

Check firebase rules you can change like this to test

```
service firebase.storage {  match /b/{bucket}/o {
match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read, write: if true;    }  }}
```

Comment: OP mentions using a download URL, which is a URL that bypasses the security rules and provides read-only public access.