# error: cannot find symbol messageTextBody.put("message", task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString());

Tags: java, android

I get the error when I compile the app. It says that

> task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString() cannot find the symbol

```
filePath.putFile(fileUri).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
         if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        Map messageTextBody = new HashMap();
                        messageTextBody.put("message", task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString());
                        messageTextBody.put("name", fileUri.getLastPathSegment());
                        messageTextBody.put("type", checker);
                        messageTextBody.put("from", messageSenderID);
                        messageTextBody.put("to", messageReceiverID);
                        messageTextBody.put("messageID", messagePushID);
                        messageTextBody.put("time", saveCurrentTime);
                        messageTextBody.put("date", saveCurrentDate);
                        Map messageBodyDetails = new HashMap();
                        messageBodyDetails.put(messageSenderRef + "/" + messagePushID, messageTextBody);
                        messageBodyDetails.put(messageReceiverRef + "/" + messagePushID, messageTextBody);
                        RootRef.updateChildren(messageBodyDetails);
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double p = (100.0*taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                        loadingBar.setMessage((int) p + " % Uploading...");
                    }
                });
```

Comment: your key("message") for task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString() must be same as server's json

Comment: its same sir but I don't know why it's giving me this error and here is the code [link](https:github.com/sadsouler/Chat)

Comment: replace task.getResult().getDownloadUrl() by task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().

Reason is mentioned on https://stackoverflow.com/a/50159199/10340422:
The getDownloadUrl() and getDownloadUrls() methods of the StorageMetadata class are now deprecated. Use getDownloadUrl() from StorageReference instead.

Comment: Sure I will try

Comment: i tried but app get crash and send me to main activity

Comment: hello @ChiragRayani i tried to replace the code with this `filePath.putFile(fileUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        filePath.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                String downloadUrl = uri.toString();`
but didnot work

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

```
task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString());
```

replace it with

```
task.getResult().toString();
```

Comment: if i do that then how will i see the documents in my phone