# Why am I getting the wrong link over and over again on getUploadUrl ? It is not working

Tags: java, android, image-uploading

I tried to resolve this with similar threads and answers here but completely failed.
My image is getting stored in firebase storage, and the database upload link is working but its always the wrong link. I get "com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@8045166" so the image is not displaying on the app

This is the overall code with the old version of GetDownloadUrl

```
private void InitializeFields()
    {
        UpdateAccountSettings = (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_settings_button);
        userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.set_user_name);
        userStatus = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.set_profile_status);
        userProfileImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.set_profile_image);
        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);

        SettingsToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.settings_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(SettingsToolBar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Account Settings");
    }




    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode==GalleryPick  &&  resultCode==RESULT_OK  &&  data!=null)
        {
            Uri ImageUri = data.getData();

            CropImage.activity()
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                    .start(this);
        }

        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
        {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                loadingBar.setTitle("Set Profile Image");
                loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, your profile image is updating...");
                loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                loadingBar.show();

                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();


                StorageReference filePath = UserProfileImagesRef.child(currentUserID + ".jpg");

                filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task)
                    {
                        if (task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Profile Image uploaded Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                            //--------------------------------------------->>
                            final String downloaedUrl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString(); **
                            //---------------------------------------------<<


                            RootRef.child("Users").child(currentUserID).child("image")
                                    .setValue(downloaedUrl)
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
                                        {
                                            if (task.isSuccessful())
                                            {
                                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Image save in Database, Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                loadingBar.dismiss();
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                String message = task.getException().toString();
                                                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                loadingBar.dismiss();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            String message = task.getException().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            loadingBar.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

i tried this

```
filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task)
                    {
                        if (task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            //--- what i tried instead of: final String downloaedUrl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();

                            final String downloadUrl = filePath.getDownloadUrl().toString();

                            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Profile Image uploaded Successfully...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: i did some search and got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43641941/how-to-get-file-url-after-uploading-them-to-firebase/50986113), can you try onSuccess instead of onComplete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `getDownloadUrl()` is executed asynchronously. So you can't call `toString()` directly after. You will need to attach a callback. Also, `getDownloadUrl()` in `UploadTask.TaskSnapshot` is deprecated. So you can do this instead:

```
filePath.putFile(resultUri).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
    @Override
    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            throw task.getException();
        }
        return filePath.getDownloadUrl();
    }
}).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            // retrieve your uri here
            Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
            Log.d("TEST", "download uri: " + downloadUri.toString());
        } else {
            // load failed. Handle exception from task.getException()
        }
    }
});
```