# This method should only be accessed from tests or within private scope

Tags: kotlin, methods, scope, admob, android-jetpack-compose

How I can Resolve this warning:

**This method should only be accessed from tests or within private scope**

It appear after I upgrade the android studio to the latest version!!!

[image]

```
@Composable
fun AppBody() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val width = LocalConfiguration.current.screenWidthDp
    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            AndroidView(
                factory = {
                    AdView(it).apply {
                        setAdSize(
                            AdSize.getCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSize(
                                context,
                                width
                            )
                        )
                        adUnitId = "*****"
                        loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
                    }
                },
            )
        },
        content = {
            Box(Modifier.padding(it)) {
                AppNavHostController(navController = navController)
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android - Firebase - TaskSnapshot - Method should only be accessed within private scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41105586/android-firebase-tasksnapshot-method-should-only-be-accessed-within-privat)

Comment: No,,,,,, @aSemy

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour on my app as well. Did you figure out what's the real issue?

Answer (score 0):

It just means whatever you're trying to change (`adUnitId` I think) has the `@VisibleForTesting` annotation.